# How is an a tag with href="./etc" resolved? Chrome not adhering to RFC 3986?

Tags: html, ruby, url, rfc3986

If I'm on a site `example.com/foo/index.html`, and there is an `a` tag with href `./bar/test.html`, I expect the URL of the linked document to be `example.com/foo/bar/test.html`. However, in web browsers such as Chrome or Firefox, this behavior seems to be different, and it resolves to `example.com/bar/test.html`.

I thought, `./` means the current directory, in this case `example.com/foo/`

Real life example: On [https://www.salzburger-landestheater.at/de/**spielplan/index.html**](https://www.salzburger-landestheater.at/de/spielplan/index.html), there is this a tag:

```
<a href="./produktionen/shakespeare-im-park-golden-lads-amp-girls.html?ID_Vorstellung=5527&amp;m=3">Shakespeare im Park: Golden Lads &amp; Girls</a>
```

If clicking on the link, Chrome sends me to [https://www.salzburger-landestheater.at/de/**produktionen**/shakespeare-im-park-golden-lads-amp-girls.html?ID_Vorstellung=5527&m=3](https://www.salzburger-landestheater.at/de/produktionen/shakespeare-im-park-golden-lads-amp-girls.html?ID_Vorstellung=5527&m=3), which is the correct location.
However, I would have expected the link to be [https://www.salzburger-landestheater.at/de/**spielplan/produktionen**/shakespeare-im-park-golden-lads-amp-girls.html?ID_Vorstellung=5527&m=3](https://www.salzburger-landestheater.at/de/spielplan/produktionen/shakespeare-im-park-golden-lads-amp-girls.html?ID_Vorstellung=5527&m=3)

When using for example Ruby, it outputs the URL I expected (which, sadly, leads to a 404 page though):

```
URI.join("https://www.salzburger-landestheater.at/de/spielplan/index.html", "./produktionen/shakespeare-im-park-golden-lads-amp-girls.html?ID_Vorstellung=5527&m=3").to_s
=> "https://www.salzburger-landestheater.at/de/spielplan/produktionen/shakespeare-im-park-golden-lads-amp-girls.html?ID_Vorstellung=5527&m=3"
```

I guess Chrome does it correctly, but I really don't understand it; isn't `/spielplan/` the current directoy referenced with `./`? Can someone point me to an official documentation?
I've found the [RFC 3986, Section 5.4.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-5.4.1), which gives following example:

> Within a representation with a well defined base URI of
>
> http://a/b/c/d;p?q
>
> a relative reference is transformed to its target URI as follows.
>
> [...]
>
> "./g"           =  "http://a/b/c/g"

For reference, the RFC example works in Ruby as expected:

```
> URI.join("http://a/b/c/d;p?q", "./g").to_s
=> "http://a/b/c/g"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just realized the issue in my "real life" example. I keep the question online in case anyone stumbles upon a similar issue.

The document `https://www.salzburger-landestheater.at/de/spielplan/index.html` defines a `base`: `<base href="https://www.salzburger-landestheater.at/de/">`

Thus, `./produktionen/shakespeare-im-park-golden-lads-amp-girls.html?ID_Vorstellung=5527&amp;m=3` correctly resolves to `base_url + href`: `https://www.salzburger-landestheater.at/de/produktionen/shakespeare-im-park-golden-lads-amp-girls.html?ID_Vorstellung=5527&amp;m=3`